# Regular expression to get a sub string between {}

Tags: json, regex

I've this string

`dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript1._jsonpCallback({"messages":[],"routes":{"fieldAliases":{"ObjectID":"ObjectID","Name":"Name","FirstStopID":"FirstStopID","LastStopID":"LastStopID","StopCount":"StopCount","Total_TravelTime":"Total_TravelTime","Total_Kilometers":"Total_Kilometers","Total_Miles":"Total_Miles","Shape_Length":"Shape_Length"},"geometryType":"esriGeometryPolyline","spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857},"features":[{"attributes":{"ObjectID":1,"Name":"Location 1 - Location 2","FirstStopID":1,"LastStopID":2,"StopCount":2,"Total_TravelTime":0.44978725961372451,"Total_Kilometers":0.11520726003715911,"Total_Miles":0.07158647252368612,"Shape_Length":140.31608185601101},"geometry":{"paths":[[[-13046166.1984,4036530.1599000022],[-13046165.647399999,4036389.8448999971]]]}}]}});`

and I want a regular expression to get this

`{"messages":[],"routes":{"fieldAliases":{"ObjectID":"ObjectID","Name":"Name","FirstStopID":"FirstStopID","LastStopID":"LastStopID","StopCount":"StopCount","Total_TravelTime":"Total_TravelTime","Total_Kilometers":"Total_Kilometers","Total_Miles":"Total_Miles","Shape_Length":"Shape_Length"},"geometryType":"esriGeometryPolyline","spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857},"features":[{"attributes":{"ObjectID":1,"Name":"Location 1 - Location 2","FirstStopID":1,"LastStopID":2,"StopCount":2,"Total_TravelTime":0.44978725961372451,"Total_Kilometers":0.11520726003715911,"Total_Miles":0.07158647252368612,"Shape_Length":140.31608185601101},"geometry":{"paths":[[[-13046166.1984,4036530.1599000022],[-13046165.647399999,4036389.8448999971]]]}}]}}`

In other words I want the substring between {...}

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: you shouldnt get info from json file using regex

Comment: what do you have tried so far?

Comment: Why dont you execute the function `dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript1._jsonpCallback()` instead and then pop odd the values you dont want? And you forget about the regex. Regex is not always the answer.. 1/10 times sure.. but not 9/10. `dojo` should be executing that function for you on second thought, you should have is a a javascript Object do: `var i = {'a':'a','b':'b'}; delete i['a']; console.log(i);` and you save yourself SOOOO much trouble!!

Comment: I want to parse that json in a rails server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
/\{[0-9A-Za-z\":\[\]\{\},\._\s-]*\}/
```

Edit: Missed `\}` before final `/`

Comment: I think this is better: http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5626da0c75622d5088050000 -- i still disagree with this approach of having to parse it using regex.